# Update to Rust 1.18 broke compilation: E0034 multiple applicable items in scope for "clone_into"

Tags: rust

I have this simple snippet of code, which uses an arena for memory allocation and a trait `CloneInto` whose purpose is to clone a structure from unknown origins into an `Arena`, adjusting the lifetimes as it goes:

```
struct Arena;

impl Arena {
    fn insert<'a, T: 'a>(&'a self, _: T) -> &'a mut T { unimplemented!() }
}

trait CloneInto<'a> {
    type Output: 'a;
    fn clone_into(&self, arena: &'a Arena) -> Self::Output;
}
```

It can be used as is:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord, Hash)]
struct Simple<'a> { a: &'a usize }

impl<'a, 'target> CloneInto<'target> for Simple<'a> {
    type Output = Simple<'target>;

    fn clone_into(&self, arena: &'target Arena) -> Simple<'target> {
        Simple { a: arena.insert(*self.a) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arena = Arena;
    let _ = Simple { a: &1 }.clone_into(&arena);
}
```

Or could, until the update to Rust 1.18. Now the [compiler emits this error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f9b23b1026041626fa0af1b93c65cade&version=stable&backtrace=0):

> ```
> error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
>   --> <anon>:25:30
>    |
> 25 |     let _ = Simple { a: &1 }.clone_into(&arena);
>    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^ multiple `clone_into` found
>    |
> note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl of the trait `CloneInto` for the type `Simple<'_>`
>   --> <anon>:18:5
>    |
> 18 | /     fn clone_into(&self, arena: &'target Arena) -> Simple<'target> {
> 19 | |         Simple { a: arena.insert(*self.a) }
> 20 | |     }
>    | |_____^
>    = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl of the trait `std::borrow::ToOwned` for the type `_`
> ```

even though I do not even import `std` or `ToOwned`!

Comment: `ToOwned` is in the [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/index.html), so yes, you *are* importing it!

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Good point. Otherwise it wouldn't cause a clash.

Answer (score 9):

This is an unfortunate effect of how method resolution works in Rust. Unlike other languages which feature overloading, in Rust the exact function to be called must be resolved unambiguously with no regard for its arguments.

In this specific case, Rust 1.18 brings a new nightly method called [`clone_into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#method.clone_into) on the `ToOwned` trait, and the `ToOwned` trait is implemented unconditionally for all types implementing `Clone` and imported automatically (via the [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/index.html)).

The fact that this method cannot be called on stable has no bearing; the method is first considered for resolution, and an error will be emitted if it is actually used.

Note that even though irking, there are benefits to this method of resolution: it is often unclear to a human being which overload is selected when several appear to be available, or why the expected overload is NOT being selected. By erring on the side of explicitness, Rust makes it a no-brainer.

Unfortunately, in this case this results in `Simple::clone_into()` becoming ambiguous.

There is no way to opt out of the `ToOwned` implementation (not without giving up `Clone` and `Copy`), so instead one must switch to an unambiguous call to `clone_into` using [Fully Qualified Syntax (FQS)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation):

```
fn main() {
    let arena = Arena;
    let _ = CloneInto::clone_into(&Simple { a: &1 }, &arena);
}
```